# rails bootstrap navbar custom css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize my bootstrap navbar. I tried writing a navbar-custom class which worked for the most part, but for some reason it's failing to get rid of this mysterious whitespace underneath the navbar.

[image]

It works when I add the styling directly like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-custom" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
```

But otherwise navbar-custom class itself won't do the job. What could be the problem?

One more question: This mysterious gray box appears when I click open a dropdown menu, click close it, and move the mouse away. I'm not sure which css is responsible for this.

[image]

custom.css.scss

```
@import 'colors';

    /* Nav Bar */

    .navbar-custom {
        background-color: $light_navy;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: white;   
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
        color: $rnc_orange;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
        color: $rnc_orange;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

application.html.erb

```
  <head>
    <title>Rush N Catch</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script href="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script href="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Comment: can you show me this in fiddle or codepen

Comment: @JishnuVS where should I look in my rails app to get js code for codepen?

Comment: did you import `custom.css.scss`?

Comment: @Penguin could you show me how to do that?

Comment: the navbar got margin-bottom:20px; remove that css , may be your issue fixed

Comment: @JishnuVS how do I overwrite the bootstrap css?
just .navbar { margin-bottom:0;} like so?

Comment: just tried it but didn't work

Comment: just give !important too